# Youtube video download using python script

Tags: python-3.x, video, youtube, pytube

i have this script for downloading the youtube video

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAGacI3JwS4')
#yt.title
#yt.thumbnail_url
#yt.streams.all()
stream = yt.streams.first()
#stream
stream.download('C:\\Users\')
```

but i wanted this to happened based on a user prompt mode.so it should ask the user to enter the url then from there take it further and download the video,so i did like this

```
>>> pk=input("Enter the url:")

Enter the url:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhklL_kStto
>>> pk

'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhklL_kStto'
>>> pk.title

<built-in method title of str object at 0x02362770>
>>> pk.stream()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
>>pk.stream()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stream'
```

so this is what the error am getting. can someone help me to solve this issue?

appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer isn't too late, but the problem is that `pk` is a string because of this:

```
pk=input("Enter the url:")
```

`pk` is assiged to a string here (aka whatever you input), so there's no way you would have created the relevant `Youtube` object.

The description you get when you enter `pk.title` attests to that where it says it's a built in method of a **str object**. You haven't even made a `YouTube` object for it to have even a `stream` method.

You can fix it like this:

```
url = input("Enter the url:")
pkl = YouTube(url)
pkl.stream()
```

Hope this helps